# Space of my filesystem in SD card for raspberry pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

Today when I tried to start my raspberry pi, I found one warning saying no enough room in file system. Then I used `df` to see the storage, it shows

```
Filesystem  1K-blocks   used   available use%  Mounted on
rootfs      6767168    6401028    0      100%   /
/dev/root   6767168    6401028    0      100%   /
```

Then I use `sudo du -s -h -x /*`to see the specific storage, it shows(not complete, I only pick the large ones)

```
...
1.3G  /home
...
2.9G  /usr
1.2G  /var
```

I want to delete some files in my SD card so I use Ubuntu linux system to read my SD card. It shows four folders: 'boot', 'SEETINGS', 'root', 'data' in Files. When I check the properties of 'root', it has 6.9G in total, 2.6G used and 4.0 free. Then I check the /root/home folder, it only take 67 MB. The /root/var takes 106MB and /root/usr takes 1.5G.

It does not match the space I get using the command above, why is that? And 'root' folder has 4.0G free space, why it shows use 100% ?

(the usage of other three folders:

`name        used    free
'boot'     14.9MB   47MB
'SEETINGS' 406.5kB  25.5MB
'data'     418kB    474MB`

Comment: Sorry, but this Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It may be more appropriate on the related sites http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ or http://superuser.com. Consider using the flag link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Thanks and Good Luck.

Comment: Try `sudo raspi-config` and then select `"Expand filesystem"`.

Comment: I run this command and it tells me 'your partition layout is not currently supported by this tool. you are probably using NOOBS, in which case your root filesystem is already expanded anyway'. Does it mean it has been expanded before?

Answer (score 0):

Did you expand your sd card using raspi-config?

There is one option there that it could solve your problem.

Comment: I run sudo raspi-config and select Expand filesystem. and it tells me 'your partition layout is not currently supported by this tool. you are probably using NOOBS, in which case your root filesystem is already expanded anyway'. Does it mean it has been expanded before?